# Homebrew CLI Emacs inserting ¯ when I press M-<

Tags: mac, emacs, hotkeys, character-encoding

When I try to navigate to the start of a buffer with `M-<`, Emacs instead inserts a weird character `¯`. How should I correct Emacs or Terminal.app to fix this?

```
$ specs emacs brew bash os
Specs:

specs 0.4
https://github.com/mcandre/specs#readme

emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.3.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

brew --version
0.9.4

bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep 'System Version'
      System Version: OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
```

**Update**

Aha!

`Terminal -> Preferences... -> Settings -> (profile) -> Keyboard -> Use option as meta key`

Comment: Note that it's OK to answer your own question :)

Comment: Not if your account is new, and SO's policies are retardedly restrictive. Don't have the karma yet.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, why not?

`Terminal -> Preferences... -> Settings -> (profile) -> Keyboard -> Use option as meta key`

Source: [Homebrew CLI Emacs inserting ¯ when I press M-<](https://superuser.com/q/626291/198070)